# Скачивание графика Highcharts без его отрисовки

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

```js
EXPORT_WIDTH = 2000;
var data = {
  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
  data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
};

function save_chart(chart, filename) {
    var render_width = EXPORT_WIDTH;
    var render_height = render_width * chart.chartHeight / chart.chartWidth

    var svg = chart.getSVG({
        exporting: {
            sourceWidth: chart.chartWidth,
            sourceHeight: chart.chartHeight
        }
    });

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.height = render_height;
    canvas.width = render_width;

    var image = new Image;
    image.onload = function() {
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, render_width, render_height);
        var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
        download(data, filename + '.png');
    };
    image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(svg);
}

function download(data, filename) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = filename;
    a.href = data
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.remove();
}


$(function() {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Client-Side Download Example'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click "Save Chart" to download chart as PNG'
        },

        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: data.categories
        },

        series: [{
            data: data.data
        }]

    });
    
    $('#save_btn').click(function() {
        save_chart($('#container').highcharts(), 'chart');
    });

});
```

```css
#container {
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<div id='container'></div>
<button id='save_btn'>Save Chart</button>
```

На сайте есть кнопка **Save Chart** . При клике на которую приходят некие данные, допустим это **data** из примера. Нужно сразу скачать изображение с графиком, но при этом не отрисовывая сам график на сайте. В примере показано с отрисовкой. В документации есть информация по экспорту, но я, если честно, из нее ничего не понял. Прошу показать как это можно сделать на реальном примере. Может предугадаю чей-то ответ: просто скрыть график, типа display:none не предлагать)) Заранее спасибо

Comment: А почему `display:none` не нравится?)

Comment: Потому что это костыль. А сайт и так хромает))

Comment: Если так логически подумать, то как можно экспортировать то, чего нет?))

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Ahtetep/v21ba4zr/8/ Вот есть пример с выводом этого изображения на экран, только мне его нужно сразу скачать. И тут меня смущает exportUrl .

Comment: В данном примере используется сервер `highcharts`, т.е. экспорт происходит не в браузере клиента, а на стороннем сервере. Если вам это надо - скачивайте изображение по полученной ссылке.

Comment: @АлександрМаринов так а не млучится никакой беды стпроизводительностью если вы его будете добавлять в дом модель при клике и после экспорта удалять